# Parsing binary data into separate variables in Python?

Tags: python

Say I open a file in Python that contains a series of binary data.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as data_file:
    logData = data_file.read()
```

I basically want to create a loop saying:

```
for each_word in logData:
       var1 = first 8 bytes
       var2 = next 16 bytes
       var3 = next 8 bytes
```

C code to generate my binary file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        FILE *file;
        int  buffer = 0x03000201;
        int  buffer2= 0x010203;
        file = fopen("test.bin", "wb");

        if (file != NULL)
        {
                fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file);
                fwrite(&buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), 1, file);
                fclose(file);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

and this basically continues until the loop is over, iterating through the bytes of data. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html), it will also allow you to interpret the binary data in many ways; you need to define the types in a string format documented with that library:

```
struct.unpack('=HHf255s', bytes)
```

The above example expects native byte-order, two unsigned shorts, a float and a string of 255 characters.

Your code example becomes:

```
for each_word in logData:
    var1, var2, var3 = struct.unpack('8s16s8s', each_word)
```

In case you get an error `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`, that is because `bytes` are expected, but you passed a `str`, so convert it to bytes and specify the encoding (in this example, UTF-8):

```
for each_word in logData:
    var1, var2, var3 = struct.unpack('8s16s8s', bytes(each_word, 'utf-8'))
```

But maybe the case that your 8/16 byte strings are long integers? In that case use the appropriate format for struct.

*EDIT*: it turns out you wanted to read 8 **bits** (not bytes), then the next 16 bits, then the next 8 bits, so you can read it as one (unsigned?) byte, one short, and another byte. The format string you should use is `'=bhb'` (or `'=BHB'` for unsigned). Example:

```
import struct
with open('test.bin','rb') as f:
    var1, var2, var3 = struct.unpack('=BHB', f.read(4))
    print(var1, var2, var3)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79588/discussion-on-answer-by-mescalinum-parsing-binary-data-into-separate-variables-i).